# Proving the Equation Involving the Square Root of (10-2√5)

Tags: roots, rationalising-denominator

Title: Proving the Equation
I am trying to prove the equation:

$$\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt{5}} = (\sqrt{5} + 1) \sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{5}}$$

I have tried simplifying both sides, but I am unable to show that they are equal. Can someone help me prove this equation?

Thank you!

Comment: Try squaring on both sides and expand the RHS.

Comment: @manoharthakur, if you do not write your attempts and efforts, your question does not meet the standards of quality of this website and consequently your post will be closed. Please, read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim that's a good approach but how can we go from RHs to LHS without using both sides at same time

Comment: @manoharthakur Again: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\sqrt{5}+1)^2 = 5 + 2\sqrt{5} + 1 = 6+2\sqrt{5}$, so the RHS can be written as
$$\sqrt{(\sqrt{5}+1)^2(5-2\sqrt{5})} = \sqrt{(6+2\sqrt{5})(5 - 2\sqrt{5})}$$
$$= \sqrt{30 -2\sqrt{5} -20}$$
$$=\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $10-2\sqrt{5}=(6+2\sqrt{5})(5-2\sqrt{5})$ and $(6+2\sqrt{5})$ is equal to $(1+\sqrt{5})^2$. The rest follows.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.